# Cannot move image over header in Excel

Tags: excel, image, excel-formula, header, formatting

I am trying to place a corporate logo into our company letterhead, and the template I've been given requires me to place the logo over where the header would be, with part of the logo extending beneath it. Hence putting the image into the header itself won't work.

I have tried importing the image and dragging it over to the desired spot, but I am unable to move it above the line where the header is.

If anyone has ideas for a fix, please let me know.

Comment: "... requires me to place the logo over where the header would be, with part of the logo extending beneath it. Hence putting the image into the header itself won't work." Have you even tried to put the image into the header? It will do exactly that: Showing the image in the header and a part of it beneath it, if the image height is higher than the header line.

Comment: I did try that but in print view it stretches the image out so it doesn't fall below the line.

Answer (score 0):

It should work just fine if you remember to size the graphic before inserting.

Shown in print preview with sheet rows by comments in cells.

[image]

Settings shown note highlighted item.
[image]